# MVC.NET Unit Testing RenderPartialViewToString

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq, httpcontext

I'm unit testing my MVC.Net 4 Application and I need some help testing the rendering of views to string.

When I'm testing the rendering of views to strings crashes.

In my controller I call the following line to create the html string to send back in a Json object.

```
String html = this.RenderPartialViewToString("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Statistics/Graphs/LineGraph.cshtml", orderData);
```

The RenderPartialViewtoString method is the following:

```
public static string RenderPartialViewToString(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
{
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName)) 
        {
            viewName = controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        }

        controller.ViewData.Model = model;

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            // Find the partial view by its name and the current controller context.
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);

            // Create a view context.
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);

            // Render the view using the StringWriter object.
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            //viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
}
```

I'm mocking the HttpContext using Moq.

```
public static Mock<HttpContextBase> MockHttpContext()
    {
        var browser = new Mock<HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase>();
        var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();

        var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
        var cookies = new HttpCookieCollection();
        var items = new ListDictionary();
        var session = new MockHttpSession();

        browser.Setup(b => b.IsMobileDevice).Returns(false);

        request.Setup(r => r.Cookies).Returns(cookies);
        request.Setup(r => r.ValidateInput());
        //request.Setup(r => r.UserAgent).Returns("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11");
        response.Setup(r => r.Cookies).Returns(cookies);
        request.Setup(r => r.Browser).Returns(browser.Object);
        //request.Setup(r => r.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath).Returns("/");
        //request.Setup(r => r.ApplicationPath).Returns("/");
        request.Setup(x => x.Form).Returns(new NameValueCollection());

        response.Setup(s => s.ApplyAppPathModifier(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns<string>(s => s);
        response.SetupProperty(res => res.StatusCode, (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);

        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Items).Returns(items);  

        return context;
    }

    public static Mock<HttpContextBase> MockHttpContext(string url)
    {
        var context = MockHttpContext();
        context.Object.Request.SetupRequestUrl(url);
        return context;
    }

    public class MockHttpSession : HttpSessionStateBase
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> m_SessionStorage = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        public override object this[string name]
        {
            get {
                try
                {
                    return m_SessionStorage[name];
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            set { m_SessionStorage[name] = value; }
        }

        public override void Remove(string name)
        {
            m_SessionStorage[name] = null;
        }
    }

    public static void SetMockControllerContext(this Controller controller,
        HttpContextBase httpContext = null,
        RouteData routeData = null,
        RouteCollection routes = null)
    {
        //If values not passed then initialise 
        routeData = routeData ?? new RouteData();
        routes = routes ?? RouteTable.Routes;
        httpContext = httpContext ?? MockHttpContext().Object;

        var requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContext, routeData);
        var context = new ControllerContext(requestContext, controller);

        //Modify controller
        controller.Url = new UrlHelper(requestContext, routes);
        controller.ControllerContext = context;
    }
```

And adding the mock context to the controller by using the method from the previous code block.

> MvcMockHelpers.SetMockControllerContext(controller, httpContextMock.Object, routeData, routeCollection);

Mocking the ViewEngine to deliver the correct view:

```
IEnumerable<string> FileExtensions = new[]
{
 "cshtml"
 };

 IViewPageActivator viewPageActivator = null;
 var view = new RazorView(controller.ControllerContext, "Areas/Admin/Views/Statistics/Graphs/LineGraph.cshtml", layoutPath: null, runViewStartPages: false, viewStartFileExtensions: FileExtensions, viewPageActivator: viewPageActivator);

  //Mocking View Engine to make sure that the Partial View To String function works.
  var engine = new Mock<IViewEngine>();
  var viewEngineResult = new ViewEngineResult(view, engine.Object);
  engine.Setup(e => e.FindPartialView(It.IsAny<ControllerContext>(), It.IsAny<string>(),     It.IsAny<bool>())).Returns(viewEngineResult);
  ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
  ViewEngines.Engines.Add(engine.Object);
```

When I then call the controller action method to render the view

> var result = controller.StatisticsUpdate(model);

I'm getting a reference null exception on `System.Web.VirtualPath.GetCacheKey()`

Stacktrace:

```
at System.Web.VirtualPath.GetCacheKey()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCacheKeyFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean& keyFromVPP)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath virtualPath)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(String virtualPath)
at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.GetCompiledType(String virtualPath)
at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
at WebUi.Extensions.ControllerExtensions.RenderPartialViewToString(Controller controller, String viewName, Object model) in d:\Element Software\PlasticRepository\Nobastore\WebUi\Extensions\ControllerExtensions.cs:line 37
at WebUi.Areas.Admin.Controllers.OverviewController.StatisticsUpdate(StatisticsModel model) in d:\Element Software\PlasticRepository\Nobastore\WebUi\Areas\Admin\Controllers\OverviewController.cs:line 97
at UnitTests.ControllerTests.Admin.OverviewControllerTest.StatisticsUpdate_View_Test() in d:\Element Software\PlasticRepository\Nobastore\UnitTests\ControllerTests\Admin\OverviewControllerTest.cs:line 147`
```

I've tried searching the source code for a couple of days now and I can't find the issue and I can't find any decent working solution on the web.

Does anybody have an answer? Am I missing something in the mocking of the httpcontext or controllercontext?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Wow that's an ambitious test design.  I've never heard of rendering views by creating a test controller as you've shown.  So I'm interested in why this route was taken?  If we look at the stack trace the only way we can proceed is to know more about "what the heck the cache key is all about".  Then we have to figure out how to inject it prior to kicking off the BuildManage... which is triggerd by the RenderPatrialViewToString....  That VirtualPath class does this: Provides a set of methods that enable a Web application to retrieve resources from a virtual file system.

Comment: The virtual path class is found in the System.Web.Hosting namespace. This tells me that something other than IIS or Visual Studio is hosting this application under test (probably your test).  So.... If this is true, apparently the virtual paths must be identified so that when the controller boots up it knows where to go to get the dependencies.  The only two I see are these: string viewName, object model).  This tells me both the view name and the model paths must be defined somewhere.

Comment: @JohnPeters first of all thanks for your comment. I'm actually not writing a test controller, I'm just trying to test a controller and checking if the view is rendered as it should be: that the Json object I'm returning to my page is build correctly.

Comment: @JohnPeters I'm aware, as stated in your 2nd comment, that the environment while testing is different from the normal application environment. But the rendering of the normal views, actionresult of viewresult of controllers, don't cause a problem. Or are they not being rendered when testing?

Comment: I hope you are not compelled or forced to have to do data content validation through view rendering.  If I were you I would push back on development and ask them to write Unit Tests that do this.  But lets say they won't.  Then why not just send in an HTTPRequest and parse the results?  That would get you on par with the GUI layer, right now you're having to get to the GUI layer from the inside outward and that's very difficult work.  Assuming you have to continue this way, then I believe this problem is that the view and model paths cannot be found when controller boots up.

Comment: Yes I'm going to have to tackle this from another angle.

Comment: I thought about this, this past weekend  I believe that you could include a web browser in your test the application.  You can then parse the DOM in the include webbrowser and write tests much easier that way.  I recommend HTMLAgiltyPack.

Comment: I'll check out the agility pack. I wanted to avoid using a browser or selenium as these are not as performent as I would like. Thanks for the thoughts. I'll post my solution when I've completed it.

Comment: Sounds good just use HTTPWebRequest to get the data and then agility to parse the information.  Keep in mind you will want to work with DEV team to separate the data from the gui, that way you can test the data response independent of the GUI.